# How to add product categories dropdown in Shop page only on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this short code in shop page

[product_categories number="12" parent="0"]

It works fine. But I have to display product categories drop down

[product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]

it doesn't work.

Comment: That shortcode does not exist http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Answer (score 1):

use this below link to get the answer..

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-create-a-shortcode-to-display-product-categories/